# Better algorithm for a date comparison task

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm

I would like some help making this comparison faster (sample below). The sample take each value in an array, attach an hour to a comparison-variable. If no matching value, it's add the value to a second array (which are concatenated later).

```
 if (ticks.TypeOf  == Period.Hour)
   while (compareAt <= endAt)
   {
      if (range.Where(d => d.time.AddMinutes(-d.time.Minute) == compareAt).Count() < 1)
         gaps.Add(new SomeValue() {
             ...some dummy values..  });

      compareAt = compareAt.AddTicks(ticks.Ticks);
   }
```

This execution is too consuming when came to i.e. hours. There are `365 * 24 = 8760` values at most in this array. In future, there will also be minutes/seconds per month `60*24*31=44640`, which means **unusable**.

If the array most often was complete (which means no gaps/empty slots), it could easily be by-passed with `if (range.Count() == (hours/day * days))`. Though, that day will not be today.

How would I solve it more effective?

One example: If ther are 7800 values in the array, we miss about 950, right? But can I find just the gaps-endings, and just create the missing values? That would make the o-notation depend on amount of gaps, not the amount of values..

One other welcome answer is just an more effective loop.

[Edit]
Sorry for bad english, I try my best to describe.

Comment: I read your question twice, and I'm still not sure what you're asking for here. "gaps in an array", are you talking about empty slots in the array? or intervals? Please rewrite your question so it makes more sense.

Comment: sorry, can't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Lasse Gaps means empty slots! Sorry for the english. Hours can span from `20110101 00:00 -- 20110601 23:00` but there are missing values i.e. between `20110303 14:00 20110304 04:00`

Comment: Wouldn't this be just sorting them, and iterating over them, and processing the differences between one item and the next? You would then easily identify any missing values.

Comment: @Lasse, hm.. that's exactly what the code sample above is doing.. and it take a lot of time when comparise hours over a year.

Comment: No, you have a loop inside a loop, the `.Where` call there is another loop. You don't have to do that. Just iterate over the items, one at a time, and compare it to the previous item. If the time difference between the two items creates a gap, there you have it.

Comment: @Lasse That's correct, I fully agree. I didn't reflect to it in case of searching better algorithm. I also think you're almost there with your idea, but how Big is the gap? Are there 1 or 15 periods missing. A +-1 scenario can't know without extra calculation.

Comment: And when we are at that point, isn't it near enough to success read the begin/end of each gaps into an array? Then loop through those, finally attach to the original array.

Comment: Obviously you have to determine what the size of the gap is by looking at the interval between the two points of time. The low performance here is related to the double loops, and even the existing code can be "optimized" somewhat by just not finding all the periods. You're not really interested in how many match, you're just interested in "does *any*" match, so you can replace `if (....Where(...).Count() < 1` with `if (!...Any(...))`, but the removal of the inner loop will give the most speedup.

Comment: Thank's Lasse. I explicitly stated your correctness 'That's correct, I fully agree.' :). No hard feelings! The loop have indeed better performance now with a if / while. Though I still hope for (first of all a answer) but also if there are a o(n!) solution available.

Answer (score 0):

Your performance is low because the range lookup is not using any indexing and rechecks the entire range every time.

One way to do this a lot quicker;

```
    if (ticks.TypeOf == Period.Hour)
    {
        // fill a hashset with the range's unique hourly values 
        var rangehs = new HashSet<DateTime>();
        foreach (var r in range)
        {
            rangehs.Add(r.time.AddMinutes(-r.time.Minute));
        }

        // walk all the hours
        while (compareAt <= endAt)
        {
            // quickly check if it's a gap
            if (!rangehs.Contains(compareAt))
                gaps.Add(new SomeValue() {     ...some dummy values..});

            compareAt = compareAt.AddTicks(ticks.Ticks);
        }
    }
```